# jQuery load information from elements in different elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-get

How do i get the href value from a link that is loaded with $.get? My scrip always uses the value that used to be in the div, not the value that was loaded afterwards.

The code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="more">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="paglink">
    <a href="/the/url/to/page/1">More</a>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

     $(".paglink a").click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.get($(".paglink a").attr('href'), function(data){ 
            $(data).find("#more").appendTo("#more");
            $(".paglink").html($(data).find(".paglink").html());
          });     
     });

});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Page that gets loaded:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="more">
    content
  </div>
  <div class="paglink">
    <a href="/the/url/to/page/2">More</a>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

In short: what do i have to write instead of

```
$(".paglink a").attr('href')
```

to get the value from the freshly loaded link?

Comment: When are you using `$.fn.eepager`? `options.link` == `defaults.link` and from what we can see you're never updating either.

Comment: `var link = $(data).find(".paglink_extern").attr('href')` inside the complete handler of the ajax function.

Comment: first of all you have an extra comma in your defaults. and second can you paste your html!!

Comment: Simplified the whole thing but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are dynamically loading elements to your html, that way the new elements have no click event attached to them because you probably attach it on document.Ready()..

jQuery has a "on" API that you could use to attach click events to DOM elements loaded dynamically.

**Try this code**

```
$(".paglink").on('click' , 'a', function(e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data){
              alert(data);
            $(data).find("#more").appendTo("#more");
            $(".paglink").html($(data).find(".paglink").html());
          });   
 });
```

This code is coorect

```
$(data).find("#more").appendTo("#more");
```

You take only the html content that belongs to `#more` element

[Additional information](http://api.jquery.com/on/)